# Value not passed to the controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<div ng-repeat="tack in feed">
    <div class="pin" ng-if="selected == tack.boards">
        <a href="{{ tack.link }}"><h3>{{ tack.title }}</h3></a>
        <img src="{{ tack.imageURL || 'http://www.designofsignage.com/application/symbol/building/image/600x600/no-photo.jpg' }}" />
        <p>
             {{ tack.desc }}
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
             <button ng-click="deleteTack(tack.link)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to pass a value in a function written in my controller. But the value is not getting passed to the controller.

A string on other arguments is getting passed except for `tack.link` or any other value fetched from `ng-repeat` label.

Comment: Could you please provide plunker?

Comment: The issue is probably that ng-if creates a new scope. Try putting ng-click="$parent.deleteTack(tack.link)", or using ng-show instead of ng-if.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PeVKqoMI0zgiqkUKX4B?p=preview Can you try to reproduce it in the plunker?

Comment: @user1476447 Take a look at my answer

Comment: thanks @NidhishKrishnan, I was stupid so realize that the pin I was deleting did not have a link. Yes its works fine. Can't vote you up I am a newbie and have just 14 rep. Will do when I am able to :)

Comment: :)...Its all in the game....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Working Fine!!!

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/62/)**

**html**

```
   <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="tack in feed">
        <div class="pin" ng-if="selected == tack.boards"> <a href="{{ tack.link }}"><h3>{{ tack.title }}</h3></a>

            <img src="{{ tack.imageURL || 'http://www.designofsignage.com/application/symbol/building/image/600x600/no-photo.jpg' }}" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />
            <p>{{ tack.desc }}</p>
            <br>
            <p>
                <button ng-click="deleteTack(tack.link)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {

    $scope.feed = [{
        boards: 'selected',
        link: 'link_1',
        title: 'title_1',
        desc:'desc_1'
    }, {
        boards: 'selected',
        link: 'link_2',
        title: 'title_2',
        desc:'desc_2'  
    }, {
        boards: 'selected',
        link: 'link_3',
        title: 'title_3' ,
        desc:'desc_3' 
    }, {
        boards: 'selected',
        link: 'link_6',
        title: 'title_6',
        desc:'desc_6' 
    }, {
        boards: 'selected',
        link: 'link_4',
        title: 'title_4',
        desc:'desc_4'
    }, {
        boards: 'selected',
        link: 'link_5',
        title: 'title_5',
        desc:'desc_5'
    }];

    $scope.deleteTack = function(link)
    {
        alert(link);
    }
});
```